# Caching multiple versions of the same table

Tags: sql

I have a problem with generating a particular table on the fly due to expensive SQL requests. I would like to pre-generate the table and simply display it to the user. The problem is: there are multiple versions of the table, and new ones will be continuously added.

Please give me some ideas on how to design a table (?) to hold these tables.
One idea that I have is to append a version number to each row in the individual tables and dump them all into a single cache table. This way, I can easily display just the requested version by filtering on version number. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? I'm not clear on what exactly you're doing, but it sounds a bit kludgy with multiple versions of tables, etc.

Comment: What database engine are you using?  Are you talking about using temporary tables in a stored procedure?

Comment: There is a certain job that uses different versions of processing logic to process literally billions of rows of data.
The table I am trying to cache is the result of analyzing the output of that job. It essentially counts up differences between the output of two consecutive logic versions, which is why the tables themselves have a version number. The user must be able to quickly switch from viewing the comparison of version n and n+1 to the comparison of version n+1 and n+2. I don't see the relevance of which database engine I am using, since this is conceptual, but this is MS SQL Server.

Comment: don't go to the doctor, tell him where it hurts, then tell him his questions are irrelevant :)  There are limitations, even conceptually, based on which RDBMS this is.

Comment: Sorry about that. Do you guys need any more information? Or is my idea the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example I may be making some assumptions here, but it sounds to me like dynamic SQL would do the trick.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
select
@sql = 'SELECT * FROM MyTableName_' + v.version
from dbo.Version as v
where v.id = 1

exec (@sql)
```

If you end up using it, just know that dynamic sql is a [cruel mistress](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). With one hand she give'th, the other she take'th away.